# Utility to search for text in a directory and display the matching lines as well as nearby lines

Tags: windows, gratis, search, text-search, file-search

I currently use [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) to search for text in files in a directory.  It will list all files containing that text in the left pane.  If I click on one of those files, it will show all of the matching lines (with the text highlighted) in the right pane along with their line numbers.

Now I need to do a search and not only do I need to see the matching lines, but I also need to look for another piece of information in one of the lines near the matching text (this piece of information could be 1 to 10 lines away).

Is there any free utility for Windows that will display the lines surrounding the matching text (ideally I could configure how many lines to show)?  Or it could just display the entire file with the matching text highlighted, along with Previous and Next buttons.

Comment: "Or it could just display the entire file with the matching text highlighted, along with Previous and Next buttons" sounds like any text editor

Comment: Not any text editor will search within multiple files though.